# fetching the items from a quick launch bar in sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, quicklaunch

I have a thing to do..
**Retrieve/fetch/get** the items from the **quicklaunch bar** of sharepoint, **programmatically**.

That is, all the quicklaunch bar items such as -lists, calendars, announcements etc of a particular site to be retrieved programmatically. Need to do it in asp.net.
kindly provide some help.

I am new to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

> SPNavigationNodeCollection nodes = web.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
>   for(int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
>                {
>             //this will let you access all the nodes available in a quick launch using nodes[i]
>                }

see this link also: http://www.mtelligent.com/journal/2007/10/7/customizing-the-quick-launch-menu-with-spnavigationnode-spna.html

Hope this helps

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.navigation.spnavigation.quicklaunch.aspx this helped me